# prevent selecting next dom when dbclicking text in contenteditable

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

I have the following contenteditable div, with mixed text and dom inside as follow :

```
some text<span> which i would </span><span>like to select </span>
```

My problem is, i would like to prevent double clicking a word to select span arround. For exemple, if i double click the word 'which', it only selects this word and it's the needed behavior. But the problem is, if i select the word 'would', it selects 'would '. How can i only select 'would' without span on double clic event ?

I tried to add whitespace before and after, but no result.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this small snippet of javascript and single words will be selectable within span elements:

```js
$('span').dblclick(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.toString().indexOf(' ') > -1)
    {
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        var start = range.startOffset;
        var finish = range.endOffset - 1;
        setSelectionRange(this, start, finish);
    }
});

function getTextNodesIn(node) {
    var textNodes = [];
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    } else {
        var children = node.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; ++i) {
            textNodes.push.apply(textNodes, getTextNodesIn(children[i]));
        }
    }
    return textNodes;
}

function setSelectionRange(el, start, end) {
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        var textNodes = getTextNodesIn(el);
        var foundStart = false;
        var charCount = 0, endCharCount;

        for (var i = 0, textNode; textNode = textNodes[i++]; ) {
            endCharCount = charCount + textNode.length;
            if (!foundStart && start >= charCount
                    && (start < endCharCount ||
                    (start == endCharCount && i <= textNodes.length))) {
                range.setStart(textNode, start - charCount);
                foundStart = true;
            }
            if (foundStart && end <= endCharCount) {
                range.setEnd(textNode, end - charCount);
                break;
            }
            charCount = endCharCount;
        }

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.selection && document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd("character", end);
        textRange.moveStart("character", start);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
some text<span> which i would </span><span>like to select </span>
```

Comment: My problem occurs even if i'm outside a span element. For exemple, if i double click the word 'text', which is outside a span, i get the following span into my selection 'text<span>', and i want only 'text'